# An abstract class in Java need not implement any methods from its implementing interface. Why?

Tags: java

Let's look at the following simple code snippet in Java.

```
interface Sum
{
    abstract public void showSum();
}

interface Mul
{
    abstract public void showMul();
}

abstract class Super implements Sum
{
    protected int x;
    protected int y;

    public Super(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    //No error, though the method showSum() of the implementing iterface Sum is commented. Why?

    /*public void showSum()
    {
        System.out.println("Sum = "+(x+y));
    }*/
}

final class Calculation extends Super implements Mul
{
    public Calculation(int x, int y)
    {
        super(x,y);
    }

    public void showSum()
    {
        System.out.println("Summation = "+(x+y));
    }

    //If showMul() is commented , it would issue a compile-time error. Why?
    public void showMul()
    {
        System.out.println("Multiplication = "+(x*y));
    }   
}

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\nEnter a number : ");
        int x=s.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEnter another number : ");
        int y=s.nextInt();

        Calculation c=new Calculation(x,y);
        c.showSum();
        c.showMul();
    }
}
```

---

Since the interface **Sum** containing only one method `showSum();` is being implemented by the abstract class **Super** , there should be necessary for the abstract class **Super** to implement that method `showSum();`. The compiler however doesn't complain at all and the program is working well with no problem at all. Why?

---

Similarly, the non-abstract final class **Calculation** is implementing the **Mul** interface and contains the actual implementation of the method `showMul();` presented in it's implementing interface. In case, if this method `showMul()` in the class **Calculation** is commented, it issues a compile-time error. Why is the same thing not applicable to that abstract class **Super**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why an abstract class implementing an interface can miss the declaration/implementation of one of the interface's methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197893/why-an-abstract-class-implementing-an-interface-can-miss-the-declaration-impleme)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `abstract` class is not real implementation class. It may contain `abstract` methods and doesnot need to `implement` the methods from the `interface`. It is concern of the REAL implementing class to define the abstract/interface methods.

See this difference between abstract class and interface

```
Interface:
public interface InterfaceClass {
    void interfaceMethod();
    //no method definition
}


//Abstract Class implementing InterfaceClass
abstract class AbsClass implements InterfaceClass{
    abstract void abstractMethod();
    public void doSomethingCommon() {
        System.out.println("Abstract class may contain method definition");
    }
    //no need to implement methods of InterfaceClass because AbsClass is abstract
}
```

And here is real class that extends `AbsClass`: **Its duty of RealClass to define all abstract methods and interface methods.** Additionally, it may `override` the defined methods in `abstract` class as well.

```
public class RealClass extends AbsClass{
    @Override
    public void interfaceMethod() {
        //implement interface method here
    }
    @Override
    void abstractMethod() {
    }
    // you may override the doSomethingCommon() of AbsClass too
    @Override
    public void doSomethingCommon() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.doSomethingCommon();
    }
}
```

Why there is no compile time error on `AbsClass`: 
 We cannot create instances of abstract class. That's why there is no meaning of displaying  error at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

Abstract classes behavior resembles interfaces in this case.

From the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html): *...abstract classes are similar to interfaces, except that they provide a partial implementation, leaving it to subclasses to complete the implementation. If an abstract class contains only abstract method declarations, it should be declared as an interface instead*

You don't implement methods in an interface that extends another interface. And you don't HAVE to implement methods in an abstract class that implements an interface.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's abstract. An abstract class is a class which is allowed to declare some methods without providing any implementation of those methods, forcing concrete subclasses doing it. You could add the method

```
@Override
public abstract void showSum();
```

to the abstract class, but it would just be redundant with the method already declared in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to be comment to JB Nizet's answer, but I cant post comments yet :(
Note that you *could* provide the implementation for the showSum() method in your abstract class, and still have that class remain abstract without any problems. An abstract class could have all methods implemented and still be abstract!

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle's Java tutorial:

> a class that implements an interface must implement all of the
>   interface's methods. It is possible, however, to define a class that
>   does not implement all of the interface's methods, provided that the
>   class is declared to be abstract.

Reference document: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html , section *When an Abstract Class Implements an Interface*.