# An interface for classes which extend Observable

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract-class, observer-pattern

I want to keep my business logic behind an interface (which is a good practice, I understand). I also want the business logic to be Observable, and Observable is a concrete class.

The other parts of the program need to know that the business logic both 1) implements my own interface, and 2) extends the Observable. And I need both, every time.

How do I do that?

Comment: check the example http://www.coderanch.com/t/380786/java/java/Observable-class-Observer-interface

Answer (score 3):

```
public abstract class MyObservable extends Observable implements MyInterface {}
```

Comment: Btw , maybe it will helpful in this context : [abstract class can implement an interface without overriding all the methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197893/why-an-abstract-class-implementing-an-interface-can-miss-the-declaration-impleme)

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob Trick? It's just the answer to the question. Pretty obvious really. Your link doesn't say anything that the word `abstract` doesn't already say.

Comment: yup , but i found it helpful for me as i did not know it explicitly. I thought it will be helpful for bargainer like me :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an interface for your interface use an abstract class that extends Observable.

```
public abstract class MyType extends Observable {
    public abstract void doSomething();
    ...
}
```